# How to catch the "Delete" keyboard event in InkCanvas, WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, keyboard, inkcanvas

There is a InkCanvas control in my application. There are two elements(A and B) in the InkCanvas. And I want to delete A element through the keyboard "Delete".

In the processing, I want to use InkCanvas.KeyDown event to catch the "Delete" keyboard event, but it does't work.

How can I do to catch the event?

The method I registered in the InkCanvas as follow:

```
private void DkpCanvasKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key==Key.Delete)
    {
        //Do method processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a [bubbling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) [routed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) is handled internally as in this case you usually can use the [tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) version, i.e. `PreviewKeyDown`. Alternatively you probably can add an [`KeyBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) to the `InkCanvas.InputBindings`.

Comment: In my experience, `PreviewKeyDown` doesn't fire on `InkCanvas` controls either. I've also tried to catch the routed event on the containing component (in my case a `Grid`), but that does not fire either.

Comment: But it will fire on parents of InkCanvas